# How do I combine Month and Year into a single column in R

Tags: r

I'd like to use the zoo library and and specifically the as.yearmon function as follows:

```
df$YearMonth <- as.yearmon(paste(df$year, df$month), "%Y %m")
```

However, the resulting "YearMonth" column showed NA for the column. Do you know what is going wrong? Is it possible that it is due to the month and year variable in my data being a factor and integer respectively?

Comment: Can you give an example of your input and output data?

Comment: Use `sep = "-"`

Comment: I have tried sep = "-" and the yearmonth column is still filled with NA

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your input data: `zoo::as.yearmon("2007-12")`  returns `[1] "Dec 2007"` Maybe the superflous fomat is screwing things up? I say again: READ the help page.

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You have to match what is inside `paste()` with the format argument `"%Y %m"` like this:

```
df$YearMonth <- as.yearmon(paste(df$year, " ", df$month), "%Y %m")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if you have appropriate inputs.  For example, all these work:

```
library(zoo)

yr <- 2001:2003
mo <- 1:3

as.yearmon(paste(yr, " ", mo), format = "%Y %m")
## [1] "Jan 2001" "Feb 2002" "Mar 2003"

as.yearmon(paste(yr, mo), format = "%Y %m")
## [1] "Jan 2001" "Feb 2002" "Mar 2003"

as.yearmon(paste0(yr, " ", mo), format = "%Y %m")
## [1] "Jan 2001" "Feb 2002" "Mar 2003"

as.yearmon(paste(yr, mo, sep = "-"))
## [1] "Jan 2001" "Feb 2002" "Mar 2003"

as.yearmon(paste0(yr, "-", mo))
## [1] "Jan 2001" "Feb 2002" "Mar 2003"

as.yearmon(yr + (mo - 1)/12)
## [1] "Jan 2001" "Feb 2002" "Mar 2003"
```